# How to 're-run' the mainloop in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I've been asked to make a Chat program using Tkinter. For the final part, I'm supposed to have the Chat window open, which has one Entry field, one Button (SEND) and a Text Widget to display the chat log. This is my first week learning Tkinter, and I've been told in class that the `mainloop()` is an infinite loop as long as the user doesn't close the window or write `root.quit()`. So in the chat window, I'm supposed to check for new messages every 10 seconds. Is it possible to do that in the `mainloop()`? If yes, please let me know how, because I have no idea how that can happen since the stuff before the `mainloop()` is read only once. For example, something like a print statement is printed only once, even though the `mainloop()` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Please add your existing code even if it does not do what you expect so others can reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `after` method of the root window to call something in the future. If that function itself calls `after`, you can set it up so that your function runs every 10 seconds forever.

```
def check_for_messages():

    <your code here>

    root.after(10000, check_for_messages)
```

Call that function once before calling `mainloop()` and it will run every 10 seconds for as long as `mainloop()` is running.